# Apply VLOOKUP formula to multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

How can I apply a VLOOKUP formula to multiple sheets in Excel 2010?

Our formula is written and it is working on our Sheet 1, but we need to search 3 Sheets (within the same Workbook), preferably simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your key is in column A (in all sheets, including the target sheet), and the data to extract is in B columns, type the following formula in column B of the target sheet:

You have to give priorities to the origin sheets.
Here I assume that you are about to look in sheet1, then in sheet2 and finally in sheet3.
The priority is important because `VLOOKUP` looks for the first matching key value.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet3!A:B,2,0),"*** Missing ***")))`

You can change the search area and extracting column number of each origin sheet, but make sure your key is always in the first column (the nearest column to column A or column A itself).

Have fun.