# Apply VLOOKUP to multiple sheets and ignore blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to do a VLOOKUP on multiple sheets (for which I am able to define a strict priority order) but where I want to ignore the answer when it is a blank. I have found this answer:

[Apply VLOOKUP formula to multiple sheets](https://superuser.com/questions/437419/apply-vlookup-formula-to-multiple-sheets)

The problem in this answer is that I am absolutely sure that all my entries will match in the first sheet, but a lot of them will match to blank cells. When that is the case, I would like for the formula to search in the second sheet, the third one, etc. until there is no sheet left. The number of sheet I have is reasonable (it will not be over 10) so I don't mind a solution requiring to explicitely write all the sheets in the formula.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't really handle 3d lookups well (across sheets) the only way you could do this that I know of is to check each cell and see if its blank if not go to the next one.  Below is an example using 3 sheets.

> =if(isbank(vlookup(f1,sheet1!A2:B10,2,false)),if(isbank(vlookup(f1,sheet2!A2:B10,2,false)),if(isbank(vlookup(f1,sheet3!A2:B10,2,false)),"no_non_blank",vlookup(f1,sheet3!A2:B10,2,false)),vlookup(f1,sheet2!A2:B10,2,false)),vlookup(f1,sheet1!A2:B10,2,false))

You might be better having a column per sheet and do all the lookups and then pick your value from the first non blank column.  It would be much more readable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but as I have to do this for a lot of columns, I don't think I can implement your last suggestion; despite the fact that indeed, it  would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  You can import the data from each target sheet as a separate Query, and filter out the blank rows.  Then you can build another Query starting from your base sheet and adding in the target sheets in turn, using the Merge command:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/merge-queries-HA104149757.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872

You can deliver the final result to an Excel Table.

Power Query is much easier to work with than complex nested vlookup expressions.  At each step you can instantly see the resulting data.